# Should MVVM models contain complex objects

Tags: database, mvvm

Let us say that I have a Book class, a book can have an object of another class like an Author or other complex objects like a list of Genres. My question is, in an MVVM model should I make the complex object a property or should I use a simple object like Integer which contains a reference to the complex object, like it's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model is much more than a dumb data object. It can (and should) contain references to other objects, hold collections and so on.

In your case, you may have an `Author`, which has a collection of `Book`, which may have a collection of `Genre`. This really depends on your data structure, but you get the idea.

A good example would be **Entity Framework**, as it follows the pattern of having the foreign key (the ID), and the object itself. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564.aspx) for more information.

There is nothing wrong with having references to other classes in your model.